# Select all rows from one table and the sum from the second table based on the third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with creating a query that will show me all rows from one table and the sum of rows from another table with the same id.

I've written a query that is not valid because it skips the rows that are empty.

```
SELECT g.name, sum(w.points), sum(w.points2) 
FROM groups g, works w, students s 
WHERE g.group_id=s.group_id AND w.student_id=s.student_id 
GROUP BY g.group_id;
```

I tried also `LEFT JOIN`, but my query have error:

```
SELECT g.name, s.name, sum(w.points) points
FROM groups g 
    LEFT JOIN students s 
    ON s.group_id=g.group_id
    LEFT JOIN works w
    ON w.student_id=s.student_id
GROUP BY g.group_id;
```

[Here fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/atiW99g2gS6kb7xATCWnFS/1)

If there is no point in the group, it does not show it at all, and I would like all groups to be displayed, even with the sum of 0.

---

Example tables
[image: Example tables]

---

Expected result

### [image: Expected result]

Comment: Please post (at least) the full query (with the SELECT clause) + error message + expected result.

Comment: However - your query [works for me](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sd53gCmh6yRw7wKaenLuCb/0)

Comment: Error was caused by `s.name`. Now its works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works when [I run it](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cqKjuEcdjH7NtkuzACD9aB/0):

```
SELECT g.name, sum(w.points), sum(w.points2)
FROM groups g LEFT JOIN
     students s
     ON g.group_id = s.group_id LEFT JOIN
     works w
     ON w.student_id = s.student_id
GROUP BY g.group_id;
```

If you want zeroes, use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT g.name, COALESCE(sum(w.points), 0),
       COALESCE(sum(w.points2), 0)
FROM groups g LEFT JOIN
     students s
     ON g.group_id = s.group_id LEFT JOIN
     works w
     ON w.student_id = s.student_id
GROUP BY g.group_id;
```

Comment: `0` is not requirement, i can get `NULL`

Comment: You've posted the original db-fiddle link. You need to klick on "Fork" after you made your changes.

Comment: It does not work without the second `LEFT JOIN`, but it's good after all

Comment: @MichałB . . . That is strange.  I ran it in the db<>fiddle, so the `LEFT JOIN` *was* there.  But I forgot to fork it.  In any case the link and the code should now be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
select subtable.name, sum(subtable.points),sum(subtable.points2) from
      (select gr.name,wr.points,wr.points2 from students as st 
       inner join works as wr on st.student_id = wr.student_id
       inner join groups as gr on gr.group_id = st.group_id) subtable
       group by subtable.name;
```

this should also work